# How Do I Print Text to Canvas Widget 1 line at a Time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having an issue with a python GUI application that involves the user guessing a 5 letter mystery word. On the window, there is a "game board" that is created using the create_rectangle() and create_line() methods from the canvas class. This is essentially like a grid, if you will. The user enters their guess at what the word is in a text box and each individual character from that word gets placed on the window using the create_text() function. The game board has 5 rows, with 5 blocks each, since the user gets 5 tries at guessing a 5 letter word. I created a function that checks each character of the user guess against the mystery word and after each character is checked, they get printed to the window. However, when this function gets executed, the whole grid gets filled with the same word 5 times. Each guess word is supposed to get displayed one at a time as the user makes a guess.

I know what I am doing wrong, as I have 2 for loops that essentially act as a 2-D array. So, when the function gets executed, both of the for loops get completely executed at once and that is not what I want. I can break the function that checks each guess word into 5 different functions and have 5 buttons that execute the different functions. However, I would be repeating code and I don't think that would be a very efficient way of implementing what I want. Any ideas on how I can implement this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Text
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import random
from collections import Counter
import time

#Generate random 5 letter word from text file
file = "words.txt" #File with 5 letter words
f = open(file, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
randomword = random.choice(lines) #generate random 5 letter word from file
print(randomword)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = '700', width = '600')
canvas.configure(background = "light sky blue")
canvas.pack()

#Create Title Lingo Balls
canvas.create_oval(85,10,155,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(175,10,245,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(265,10,335,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(355,10,425,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(445,10,515,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)

letterfont = tkFont.Font(size = 30)
l = canvas.create_text((120, 46), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
i = canvas.create_text((210, 46), text= "I", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
n = canvas.create_text((300, 46), text= "N", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
g = canvas.create_text((390, 46), text= "G", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
o = canvas.create_text((480, 46), text= "O", font = letterfont, fill = "white")

#Create Countdown Clock
canvas.create_rectangle(145,100,255,160, outline = "grey", fill = "grey", width = 2)
canvas.create_text((200,135), text = "2:00") #place holder text

#Create Score Box
canvas.create_rectangle(345,100,455,160, outline = "grey", fill = "grey", width = 2)
canvas.create_text((400,130), text = "100") #place holder text

#Create Game Board
canvas.create_rectangle(255,280,325,350, outline = "blue", fill = "blue", width = 200)
canvas.create_line(209,180,209,450, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(263,180,263,450, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(317,180,317,450, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(371,180,371,450, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(155,234,425,234, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(155,288,425,288, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(155,342,425,342, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(155,396,425,396, fill = "white")

#Create User Entry Text Box
guess = tk.Entry(root)
guess.place(relx = 0.263, rely = 0.88)

#Check user input against mystery word
def checkword():
   x1 = 155 #first x coordinate for placing letter
   x2 = 209 #second x coordinate for placing letter
   y1 = 180 #first y coordinate for placing letter
   y2 = 234 #second y coordinate for placing letter
   centerx = 182 #initial value for middle of square horizontally
   centery = 207 #initial value for middle of square vertically
   
   for i in range(0,5): #take 5 guesses at what mystery word is
      for j in range(0,5): #check each letter in guess input against mystery word
         if(guess.get()[j] == randomword[j]): #replace empty character with letter of random word if correctly guessed
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1+(j*54),y1+(i*54),x2+(j*54),y2+(i*54), outline = "white", fill = "red")
            
         if(guess.get()[j] in randomword and guess.get()[j] != randomword[j]):
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1+(j*54),y1+(i*54),x2+(j*54),y2+(i*54), outline = "white", fill = "yellow")
            

         letter = canvas.create_text((centerx+(j*54), centery+(i*54)), text= guess.get()[j].upper(), font = letterfont, fill = "white")
         
      
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Show", command = checkword)
button.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.88)

#Create Game Announcement Box
canvas.create_rectangle(175,465,405,515, outline = "grey", fill = "grey")
canvas.create_text((290,490), text = "Correct word is grill")

#Create Buttons
buttonfont = tkFont.Font(size = 15)
play = tk.Button(root, text = "Play Again", bg = "yellow", fg = "white", height = 1, width = 8, font = buttonfont)
rules = tk.Button(root, text = "Home", bg = "yellow", fg = "white", height = 1, width = 8, font = buttonfont)

play.place(relx = 0.25, rely = 0.775)
rules.place(relx = 0.55, rely = 0.775)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: create one function which gets argument and run it many times with different arguments. This way you write the same code only once but you can run it many times to get different results.

Comment: create a function with the argument myString or something and set myString to canvas.create_text(arguments). And then you can run it whenever you want to write to the canvas. So basically what @furus said

Comment: I see what you guys are saying, but I'm not sure you totally understand what I'm trying to do. Perhaps I didn't explain myself too good. I create a button in my code that executes the function when it gets clicked. It has a command attribute that is the name of the function to be executed. Also, when I use the create_text() function, it displays the individual characters of the string(user input). So, creating the function with an argument of myString wouldn't be helpful, since myString is the whole string, not the individual characters to be printed in different places.

Comment: Also, with buttons executing functions in tkinter, I'm not sure how I would implement creating a function with an argument, that would lead to working code. I tried doing what furas said, but the code wouldn't run.

Comment: The `for i` loop should be removed inside `checkword()`.  For your case, `i` should be a global variable which is increased by one every time the function is executed until it reaches 5.

Comment: Hey, acw1668. I have tried doing what you recommended, but the code still doesn't do what I want it too. When I click the button the first time after input is entered, it will place the characters of the string on the bottom row of the grid. Then, when I enter another string and hit the button, it will place the letters of the new guess word on top of the old ones. Check my updated solution below.

Comment: Don't forget that as the user makes a new guess, that new string should be displayed as individual characters on the row below the previous one, not on top of the characters belonging to the previous string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what tried to do that was recommended by acw1668.

```
#Check user input against mystery word
global i
i = 0
while(i < 5):
   def checkword():
      x1 = 155 #first x coordinate for placing letter
      x2 = 209 #second x coordinate for placing letter
      y1 = 180 #first y coordinate for placing letter
      y2 = 234 #second y coordinate for placing letter
      centerx = 182 #initial value for middle of square horizontally
      centery = 207 #initial value for middle of square vertically
   
      for j in range(0,5): #check each letter in guess input against mystery word
         if(guess.get()[j] == randomword[j]): #replace empty character with letter of random word if correctly guessed
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1+(j*54),y1+(i*54),x2+(j*54),y2+(i*54), outline = "white", fill = "red")
            
         if(guess.get()[j] in randomword and guess.get()[j] != randomword[j]):
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1+(j*54),y1+(i*54),x2+(j*54),y2+(i*54), outline = "white", fill = "yellow")
            

         letter = canvas.create_text((centerx+(j*54), centery+(i*54)), text= guess.get()[j].upper(), font = letterfont, fill = "white")
         #letter = canvas.create_text((centerx+(j*54), centery), text= guess.get()[j].upper(), font = letterfont, fill = "white")
      
      
   i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the `for i` loop should be removed and `i` should be a global variable that will be increased by one when the function is executed until it reaches 5:

```
#Check user input against mystery word
i = 0
def checkword():
   global i
   x1 = 155 #first x coordinate for placing letter
   x2 = 209 #second x coordinate for placing letter
   y1 = 180 #first y coordinate for placing letter
   y2 = 234 #second y coordinate for placing letter
   centerx = 182 #initial value for middle of square horizontally
   centery = 207 #initial value for middle of square vertically
   
   if i < 5:
      for j in range(0,5): #check each letter in guess input against mystery word
         if(guess.get()[j] == randomword[j]): #replace empty character with letter of random word if correctly guessed
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1+(j*54),y1+(i*54),x2+(j*54),y2+(i*54), outline = "white", fill = "red")
            
         if(guess.get()[j] in randomword and guess.get()[j] != randomword[j]):
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1+(j*54),y1+(i*54),x2+(j*54),y2+(i*54), outline = "white", fill = "yellow")
            

         letter = canvas.create_text((centerx+(j*54), centery+(i*54)), text= guess.get()[j].upper(), font = letterfont, fill = "white")
      i += 1
   else:
      print('No more guess!')
```

*Note:* better rename `i` to other meaningful name.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the function executes the way I want it to now. This was a good lesson on how to use a global variable and loops the proper way. I will learn from this for sure